# Convert Scala code to Pyspark :Word2Vec Scala Tranform Routine

Tags: scala, pyspark, nlp, vectorization, data-science

I want to translate following routine from  class [Word2VecModel]https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.3/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/Word2Vec.scala 
into pyspark.

```
  override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
        transformSchema(dataset.schema, logging = true)
        val vectors = wordVectors.getVectors
          .mapValues(vv => Vectors.dense(vv.map(_.toDouble)))
          .map(identity) // mapValues doesn't return a serializable map (SI-7005)
        val bVectors = dataset.sparkSession.sparkContext.broadcast(vectors)
        val d = $(vectorSize)
        val word2Vec = udf { sentence: Seq[String] =>
          if (sentence.isEmpty) {
            Vectors.sparse(d, Array.empty[Int], Array.empty[Double])
          } else {
            val sum = Vectors.zeros(d)
            sentence.foreach { word =>
              bVectors.value.get(word).foreach { v =>
                BLAS.axpy(1.0, v, sum)
              }
            }
            BLAS.scal(1.0 / sentence.size, sum)
            sum
          }
        }
        dataset.withColumn($(outputCol), word2Vec(col($(inputCol))))
      }
```

Can some one help me how to convert this into pyspark equivalent code? I tried to do some of the portion in bits and pieces but not able to put whole.

Like I found BLAS.axpy() inner implementation which I can leverage for pyspark is

```
axpy(double a, Vector x, Vector y)
    y += a * x
```

Same way for BLAS.scal() , the inner logic is

```
scal(double a, Vector x)
    x = a * x
```

For scala idenity function I created same function in pyspark as pyspark dosen't have one.

```
   def identity(x):
        return x
```

I tried to convert following line

```
 val vectors = wordVectors.getVectors
      .mapValues(vv => Vectors.dense(vv.map(_.toDouble)))
      .map(identity)
```

And I came up with this, not sure how to do vv.map(_.toDouble) in pyspark ? Is that right

```
  vectors_final = model.getVectors().rdd.mapValues(lambda vv: Vectors.dense(vv)).map(lambda x: identity(x))
```

Thank you.

Comment: why you doesn't use pyspark `ml package` ? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=word2vec

Comment: @BorisAzanov I am using pyspark library but I am trying to understand the transform logic of Word2VecModel.scala as there is no equivalent pyspark implementation in Github. I believe it calls under the hood this scala API code. The usecase I am working on we might get just Word2Vec dataframe instead of model to apply vectorization, hence it is needed for me to understand this logic and translate. There is very limited Word2VecModel information for pyspark.ml.feature.