# replace/lookup values of one column in a spark df by values in another dataframe pyspark

Tags: pyspark, vectorization, data-science

I have one data-frame with list of tokens.

```
data1 = [(1,  ["This","is", "category", "A"]),
    (2,  ["This", "is", "category", "B","This", "is", "category", "B"]),
    (3,  ["This", "is", "category", "F","This", "is", "category", "C"])]

df2=spark.createDataFrame(data1).withColumnRenamed('_1','category').withColumnRenamed('_2','tokens')
```

I have another dataframe with tokens and their vector representation. Here is the schema for second one

```
StructType(List(StructField(word,StringType,true),StructField(vector,ArrayType(DoubleType,true),true)))

word  vector
you   [0.04986, 0.5678]
```

I want to look up the list of tokens into the data frame with vector representation and calculate the mean in pyspark.

Please let me know how I can do this efficiently in pyspark.

The logic in python/panda is per http://nadbordrozd.github.io/blog/2016/05/20/text-classification-with-word2vec/

```
return np.array([
            np.mean([word2vec[w] for w in words if w in word2vec]
                    or [np.zeros(dim)], axis=0)
            for words in X
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple ways to achieve this. I can take you through an way i would generally prefer to do..

Step #1:
Convert the 2nd dataframe into Map and broadcast the object.. Providing an example in scala

```
val map = df.collect().map(r => r.getString(0) -> r.getString(1)) 
val broadcasted_map = sc.broadcast(map)
```

Step #2:
Create UDF function to perform your required mean operation and inside UDF function you can access the broadcasted map using broadcasted_map.values.get("word")

```
val udf_function = udf((token: String) => {
// place your mean function here and access map here for word lookup
})
df.withcolumn("mean_value", udf_function(col("tokens"))) //add your transformation column
```

Since the map is broadcasted, it will be available in all worker nodes and lookup is local to the node and involves no shuffle..

Comment: Hi @Naresh Krishnamoorthy , Thank you for your reply currently I am using udf and will try broadcast the dictionary to all executors. I am wondering   Is there any other way where I can translate mean logic without using numpy in pyspark?  I came across the Word2VecModel.scala Transform logic, I feel it is doing similar operations to achieve the embedding . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290999/convert-scala-code-to-pyspark-word2vec-scala-tranform-routine. I tried to translate few pieces but I am not strong in pyspark.